# Телеграм бот тех поддержка

Tags: python, sqlite

Разрабатываю телеграм бота тех поддержки, написал код с базой данных sqlite, и в боте можно общаться но бот связывает не оператора и пользователя, а всех пользователей на рандом, как сделать так чтобы бот связывал оператора и пользователя?

```
# получение чата     
    def get_chat(self):
        with self.connection:
            chat = self.cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM queue', ()).fetchmany(1)
            if bool(len(chat)):
                for row in chat:
                    return row[1]
            else:
                return False
#создание чата между пользователями         
    def create_chat(self, chat_one, chat_two):
        with self.connection:
            if chat_two != 0:
                self.cursor.execute("DELETE FROM queue WHERE chat_id = ?", (chat_two,))
                self.cursor.execute('INSERT INTO chats (chat_one, chat_two) VALUES (?,?)', (chat_one, chat_two,))
                return True

            else:
                return False
#получение чата        
    def get_active_chat(self, chat_id):
        with self.connection:
            chat = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM chats WHERE chat_one = ?", (chat_id,))
            id_chat = 0
            for row in chat:
                id_chat = row[0]
                chat_info = [row[0], row[2]]

            if id_chat == 0:
                chat = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM chats WHERE chat_two = ?", (chat_id,))
                for row in chat:
                    id_chat = 0
                    chat_info = [row[0], row[1]]

                if chat_id == 0:
                    return False
                else:
                    return chat_info
            else:
                return chat_info
```